# What is the impact of Universal analytics deprecation on Magento 2

Tags: magento, google-analytics, magento2, universal-analytics, magento2.4

To send ecommerce data from Magento 2 to analytics, we have out of the box configuration in admin Magento 2. In which we are adding universal tracking ID (UA-XXXXXXX-1), then its starts sending ecommerce data from Magento 2 website to Analytics.

But now in the Analytics dashboard we are seeing that Universal Analytics will stop processing data starting July 1, 2023. In this case how we will send ecommerce data to analytics. Is there any configuration changes we need to do from Magento 2 side?

What is the impact of this on Magento 2 configuration.

I need to understand going forward how we are sending ecommerce data from Magento 2 to analytics.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The deprecation is no limited just to Magento. This will impact every website using the Universal analytics built on any platform.

**Understand what's going to happen**

- Beginning in March 2023, if you haven't already created a GA4 property, we'll create one for you, unless you opt out. This new property will be based on the settings in your Universal Analytics property. If you have created a GA4 property, and that property is connected to a Universal Analytics property, we'll copy over any configurations (e.g., goals, audiences, etc.) from your Universal Analytics property that you have not marked as complete in your GA4 property, unless you opt out.
- Until July 1, 2023, you can continue to use and collect new data in your Universal Analytics properties. Some properties will continue to process data for a short period after this as we stage the shutdown of Universal Analytics.
- After July 1, 2023, you'll be able to access your previously processed data in your Universal Analytics property for at least six months. We know your data is important to you, and we strongly encourage you to export your historical reports during this time.
- In the coming months, we'll provide a future date for when existing Universal Analytics properties will no longer be available. After this future date, you'll no longer be able to see your Universal Analytics reports in the Analytics interface or access your Universal Analytics data via the API.

For more details read the following article.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528

Comment: Hi @Mukesh, thanks for your response. I need to understand the going forward how we need send ecommerce data from magento 2 analytics.

Comment: @Mani I have used https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-4-ga4-with-gtm-support-for-magento-2.html in one of my project. (I am not endorsing it) . You may discuss with you team which manages the GA account for you and then decide next action item. There are many plugins available in market.

Comment: HI @Mukesh. Could you clarify this,  is it won't work if we replace the UA tracking ID with GA4 tracking ID in Magento 2 admin configuration. Is it won't send ecommerce data?

Comment: @Mani if you just change the GA4 id with UA ID it won't work automatically.